# Queue using Array>>shifting elements after popping

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a queue using an array. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#define SIZE 5

class queue
{
    int *Queue, front, rear;

    public:
    queue() {
        Queue = new int[SIZE];
        front = rear = -1;
    }

    void push() {
        if (rear == (SIZE-1)) {
            cout<<"\n Overflow!";
        } else {
            rear++;
            cout<<"\n Enter element: ";
            cin>>Queue[rear];   
        }
    }

    void pop() {
        if (front == rear) {
            cout<<"\n Underflow!";
        } else {
            cout<<"\nElement popped: "<<Queue[++front];
        }
    }

    void display() {
        if (front == rear) {
            cout<<"\n Queue Empty";
        } else {
            for(int i = (front+1); i<=rear; i++) {
                cout<<Queue[i]<<" ";
            }
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    int choice;
    queue q;
    while(choice != 4)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n Enter your choice :"
            <<"\n 1. Push an element into Queue."
            <<"\n 2. Pop an element from Queue."
            <<"\n 3. Display the Queue."
            <<"\n 4. Exit the program.\n\n";
        cin>>choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                q.push();
                break;
            case 2:
                q.pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                q.display();
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that once the overflow is met, even after popping an element the rear remains the same and another element is not added when there is a vacant space where it can go.

The solution for this could be to shift every element one place ahead so that there is empty spot at the end but I am having trouble with the shift. Also, if I try inserting after popping 2-3 times before reaching overflow then it still gives overflow even when there are only 3 elements in the queue.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Please edit your post to fix your indentation. Use spaces for indentation on Stack Overflow (even though not in your real code!)

Comment: What on earth is `<iostream.h>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `front` or `rear`, they keep increasing forever.

the overlflow test is also wrong:

```
if (rear == (SIZE-1)) {
        cout<<"\n Overflow!";
```

what you should be testing is if your are about to overwrite front. I think you will benefit from keeping just `front` and the number of elements `N` instead. Then overflow and underflow becomes `N>SIZE` and `N==0` instead. Then just increase and decrease `N` as you pop and push. Keep front as it is but also keep it modulo `SIZE`.

Also, as written in a comment. No need to move around the data.

Comment: yea.. thanks
also i am trying to add a shift loop which shifts the elements.

Comment: what i am trying to do is keep the front constant and reset rear after shifting elements one place ahead.
         cout<<"\nElement popped: "<<Queue[front+1];
instead of [++front]  that would keep front from increasing forever.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to avoid the need to shift the whole data.

Comment: front++ would give a garbage value at the first pop after overflow is met.

Comment: Of course you need to reduce `front` modulo the queue size as described in the linked article: `front %= SIZE`.